# Sphinx cannot find module for autodoc even after including it in sys.path

Tags: module, operating-system, sys, autodoc

I have a large directory structure so instead of manually adding the paths, i am searching for all modules using `os.walk()`. Whenever I am finding a directory containing a `__init__.py` file I am including that directory in the `PYTHONPATH` by using the following code in my `conf.py` file:
    import os, sys

```
top = "/home/userme/Desktop/root"
for dirpaths, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top):
    if "__init__.py" in filenames:
        sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(dirpath))
```

I am also printing the filepaths to see that they are correct. Even then while trying to read the corresponding rst file I am getting an error trying to import the module.

Comment: I am using virtualenvwrapper so also take that into account.

Comment: I just noticed a typo in my code written in the question `for dirpaths, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top):`, please note that it would be `dirpath`. That was correct, even then the error for `no module` persisted.